# Simple make question, trying to understand lmbench makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am looking at the dry run after running lmbench makefile. I could not understand what is `all` doing in this line:

```
cd src && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ankur/lmbench/lmbench-3.0-a9/src'
env CFLAGS=-O MAKE="`../scripts/make`" MAKEFLAGS="wn" CC="`../scripts/compiler`"     OS="`../scripts/os`" ../scripts/build all
```

Comment: please post the relevant parts of the `makefile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: It is a parameter to the script ../scripts/build.

Breaking that line down (apologies if I'm explaining stuff you already know):

- `env` - sets up the environment for the called script.  Format is `env VAR1=value1 VAR2=value2 command argument1 argument2`.  Putting `-` (which isn't here) would empty the environment, but this usage adds to/updates the existing one.
- `` CFLAGS=-O MAKE="`../scripts/make`" MAKEFLAGS="wn" CC="../scripts/compiler"     OS="`../scripts/os`" `` - the environment variables that are being set.  The backticks (`` `../scripts/make` `` indicate executing a script to get the value to place into the variables.
- `../scripts/build` - This is the command to run.
- `all` - This is the first (and only) argument to the command.